Odoo 16: Context not passed correctly when creating a new contact
I am working on an Odoo 16 module and I'm facing an issue with context passing when creating a new contact from my module. Specifically, I have three custom fields that should only be visible when a certain context is present, but they are not showing up as expected.
When I start writing in the contact_id field and click "create and edit", the context should be passed so that I can fill out the additional fields in res.partner, but it doesn't work. However, when I click on a contact that already exists, the context is being passed correctly and the fields are visible.
res_partner.py:
from odoo import models, fields, api

class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    age = fields.Integer(string="Age", tracking=True)
    sex = fields.Selection([
        ('male', 'Male'),
        ('female', 'Female'),
        ('other', 'Other')
    ], string="Sex", tracking=True)
    occupational_group = fields.Selection([
        ('white_collar', 'White Collar'),
        ('blue_collar', 'Blue Collar'),
        ('other', 'Other')
    ], string="Occupational Group", tracking=True)
    show_claim_fields = fields.Boolean(string="Show Claim Fields", compute="_compute_show_claim_fields")

    @api.depends_context('default_from_claims')
    def _compute_show_claim_fields(self):
        for partner in self:
            partner.show_claim_fields = self.env.context.get('default_from_claims', False)



res_partner_views.xml:
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="view_partner_form_inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">res.partner.form.inherited</field>
            <field name="model">res.partner</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='vat']" position="after">
                    <field name="age" attrs="{'invisible': [('show_claim_fields', '=', False)]}"/>
                    <field name="sex" attrs="{'invisible': [('show_claim_fields', '=', False)]}"/>
                    <field name="occupational_group" attrs="{'invisible': [('show_claim_fields', '=', False)]}"/>
                    <field name="show_claim_fields" invisible="1"/>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>

claim_details_views.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>


<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_create_claim">
    <field name="name">Add claim</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">claim.details</field>
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    <field name="target">new</field>
    <field name="context">{'default_policy_number': policy_number}</field>
</record> 

<record id="action_create_contact" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Create Contact</field>
    <field name="res_model">res.partner</field>
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    <field name="target">new</field>
    <field name="context">{'default_from_claims': True}</field>
</record>


    <record id="claim_details_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">claim.details.view.form</field>
        <field name="model">claim.details</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Claim Details">
                <sheet>
                 <group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="force_readonly" invisible="1"/>
                            <field name="external_policy_number" attrs="{'readonly': [('force_readonly', '=', True)]}"/>
                            <field name="date_claimed"/>
                            <field name="initial_reserve"/>
                            <field name="claim_note"/>
                            <field name="accident_date"/>
                            <field name="contact_id" options="{'no_quick_create': True, 'action': 'action_create_contact'}" context="{'default_from_claims': True}"/>
                            <field name="external_claim_number"/>
                            <field name="cause_of_claim"/>
                        </group>

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
